# Grails - access data within Config.groovy whilst using variable in path

Tags: grails, config

I know that to access a variable from within the Config.groovy file,

```
grailsApplication.config.someValue.anotherValue
```

I want to use a variable within this path because I want to get a URL from the config file. The value foo is passed in as a parameter to the method which will be called a number of times using different variables based on other factors.

```
def foo = "anothervalue"
grailsApplication.config.someValue.${ foo }.
```

The actual path to the value I want in the config stays the same as in the first instance.

I have tried:

```
grailsApplication.config.someValue.${ foo }
grailsApplication.config.someValue${ foo }
grailsApplication.config.someValue + "${ foo }"
grailsApplication.config.someValue + ".${ foo }"
grailsApplication.config.someValue + ${ foo }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grailsApplication.config.someValue."${ foo }"` must works.

`grailsApplication.config` returns a [`groovy.util.ConfigObject`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html#getConfig()) like `groovy.util.ConfigSlurper.parse()` so you can see how it works in the follow example:

```
import groovy.util.ConfigSlurper

def configTxt = '''
prop1 {
    prop2 {
        person.name = 'paco'
    }
}
'''

def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(configTxt)
def foo = "prop2"
println config.prop1."${foo}" // prints [person:[name:paco]]
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

more natural would be `grailsApplication.config.someValue[ foo ]`